# GLenum and GLint not declared when using GL Load

Tags: c++, opengl

Something like this doesn't compile because `GLenum` and `GLint` aren't declared in namespace `gl`:

```
#include <glload/gl_3_3.hpp>
#include <glload/gll.hpp>

void foo(gl::GLenum, gl::GLint);
```

How can I use `GLenum` and `GLint` with GL Load?

Comment: @Andrew Why are they not in the `gl` namespace?

Comment: possibly because using gl::GLenum is a bit strange because you are repeating `gl`. And you can't write gl::enum since enum is a keyword. The same applies to int

Comment: @Pubby: From the documentation: "There are some declarations that cannot be moved to a namespace. The glext_ variables cannot be moved to the gl namespace. The OpenGL defined types (GLfloat, GLint, etc) also are not placed in the namespace."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [link](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/group__module__glload.html) it seems you are only required to do `GLuint` instead of `gl::GLuint`. I would assume this is the case of `GLenum` and `GLint` too.